# PEB_LDR_DATA on x64bit

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

What is the address of `_PEB_LDR_DATA` from the start of PEB?
Somewhere is says `One of those structures is a pointer to _PEB_LDR_DATA within offset 0x0c from the start of the PEB.`

and somewhere it says  `PVOID64 LDR_DATA_Addr = *(PVOID64**)((BYTE*)Peb+0x018); //0x018 is the LDR relative to the PEB offset. The base address of the LDR is stored.`

so i am confused.

and, what does this code mean?

```
dataTableEntry = *(_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY **)(*(int *)(*(int *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x30) + 0xc) + 0xc);
baseDllNamePtr2 = &dataTableEntry->BaseDllName;
dataTableEntry = (_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY *)(dataTableEntry->InLoadOrderLinks).Flink;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [PEB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb) structure, you'll see the following:

> ```cpp
> typedef struct _PEB {
>   BYTE                          Reserved1[2];
>   BYTE                          BeingDebugged;
>   BYTE                          Reserved2[1];
>   PVOID                         Reserved3[2];
>   PPEB_LDR_DATA                 Ldr;
>   // ...
> } PEB, *PPEB;
> ```

The first 3 entries (`Reserved1`, `BeingDebugged`, and `Reserved2`) take up 4 bytes on x86 and x64. After that, the offset calculation changes between 32-bit and 64-bit code.

In 32-bit code, pointers are 4-byte aligned. Thus, there is no padding between `Reserved2` and `Reserved3`. With `Reserved3`'s size being 8 bytes (2 4-byte pointers), the offset of `Ldr` evaluates to `2 * 1 + 1 + 1 * 1 + 0 + 2 * 4` (i.e. `12` or `0x0C`).

In 64-bit code there are 2 differences: pointers are 8 bytes in size, and 8-byte aligned. The latter introduces padding between `Reserved2` and `Reserved3`. The offset of `Ldr` thus evaluates to `2 * 1 + 1 + 1 * 1 + 4 + 2 * 8` (i.e. `24` or `0x18`).

The following table summarizes the offsets for x86 and x64:

| Field | Offset (x86) | Offset (x64) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Reserved1` | 0 | 0 |
| `BeingDebugged` | 2 | 2 |
| `Reserved2` | 3 | 3 |
| `Reserved3` | 4 | 8 (padding) |
| `Ldr` | 12 | 24 |